# Angular pipe that transforms number to readable fraction

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I would like to create an Angular 5 pipe that translates a more readable fraction from a number.

For example:

```
0,66 -> ⅔
0,25 -> ¼
1.25 -> 1 ¼
```

Here is what I already have, but I would like to make it more dynamic:

```
export class FracturePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let roundedValue = Math.round(Number(value) * 100) / 100

    if (roundedValue === 0.66) {
      return '⅔'
    }
    //..and so on, but maybe there is a better way
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to do that in a more dymamic way?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do this using external libraries this is more than possible with typescript, using the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) you can calculate the Greatest common divisor between two numbers and divide by your decimal value, where this decimal value is calculated at

```
const wholeNumber = Math.floor(input);
const decimal = input - wholeNumber;
```

The return of this pipe is a string first followed by the integer value of the number then the fraction that is calculated ( decimal divided by gcd  and bottom of fraction divided by gcd )

Example : 1.3 will return **1 3/10**
You then can edit the output of the pipe as your liking

```
 export class FracturePipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

  if (value === parseInt(value)) {
        return value.toString();
      } else {
        let top = value.toString().includes('.') ? value.toString().replace(/\d+[.]/, '') : 0;
        const wholeNumber = Math.floor(value);
        const decimal = value - wholeNumber;
        const bottom = Math.pow(10, top.toString().replace('-', '').length);
        if (decimal >= 1) {
          top = +top + (Math.floor(decimal) * bottom);
        } else if (decimal <= -1) {
          top = +top + (Math.ceil(decimal) * bottom);
        }

        const x = Math.abs(this.gcd(top, bottom));
        if (wholeNumber === 0) {
          return (top / x) + '/' + (bottom / x);
        }
        return wholeNumber + ' ' + (top / x) + '/' + (bottom / x);
      }
}

gcd(a: number, b: number) {
    return (b) ? this.gcd(b, a % b) : a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [fractionjs](https://github.com/ekg/fraction.js) to get it working. I haven't worked with it, but really the problem is number conversion. So if you managed to get those two working together, I think it could be something as follows:

```js
export class FractionPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): string {
        const { numerator, denominator } = new Fraction(value);

        return `${numerator} and ${denominator} formatted`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This library might help, if you pass two values instead of the finished float: https://github.com/ben-ng/vulgarities

```
var characterFor = require('vulgarities/charFor')
  , vulgarities = require('vulgarities');

console.log(characterFor(1,4)); // Returns "\u00BC"
```

If you combine this with the answer of EvaldasBuinauskas, you get something like this:

```
export class FractionPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): string {
        const { numerator, denominator } = new Fraction(value);

        return characterFor(numerator, denominator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one way flow syntax property binding:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<p>I will display &frac34;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
export class AngularFractions {

  fraction: any;
  input: number;
  public dynamicFractions(input) {
    this.fraction = '&frac' + input + ';';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input class="form-control" (change)="dynamicFractions(input)" [(ngModel)]="input"><br>
  <p [innerHTML]="fraction"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made this pipe to support recipe portions. It is only for positive values and not comprehensive for all fractions:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'quantity',
  standalone: true,
})
export class QuantityPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(quantity: number): string | number {
    const decimal = quantity % 1;
    if (!decimal) return quantity;

    const whole = Math.floor(quantity);
    if (approxEq(decimal, 1 / 2)) return whole ? `${whole} ½` : '½';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 1 / 3)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅓` : '⅓';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 2 / 3)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅔` : '⅔';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 1 / 4)) return whole ? `${whole} ¼` : '¼';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 3 / 4)) return whole ? `${whole} ¾` : '¾';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 1 / 5)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅕` : '⅕';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 2 / 5)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅖` : '⅖';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 3 / 5)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅗` : '⅗';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 4 / 5)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅘` : '⅘';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 1 / 6)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅙` : '⅙';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 5 / 6)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅚` : '⅚';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 1 / 8)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅛` : '⅛';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 3 / 8)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅜` : '⅜';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 5 / 8)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅝` : '⅝';
    if (approxEq(decimal, 7 / 8)) return whole ? `${whole} ⅞` : '⅞';

    return Number(quantity.toFixed(2));
  }
}

const approxEq = (v1: number, v2: number, epsilon: number = 0.005): boolean =>
  Math.abs(v1 - v2) < epsilon;
```